# What do I need to return from __repr__ to have multiple lines when printing custom object wrapped in a pandas object

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

consider my custom class `Cube`

```
class Cube(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "⧉ ⟦x⨯y⟧\nCUBE"

cube = Cube()

cube

⧉ ⟦x⨯y⟧
CUBE
```

The string representation was printed on multiple lines.
However, when I wrap it in a pandas `pd.Series` it prints on one line

```
pd.Series(cube)

0    ⧉ ⟦x⨯y⟧\nCUBE
dtype: object
```

Same thing with a `pd.DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame([cube])
```

[image]

---

***I don't want `\n` to be printed.  I want a newline.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a good answer for your actual question, but in the past when I've wanted to change some of the visuals of a DataFrame's HTML table, I've used a combination of `IPython.display.display_html()` and `pd.DataFrame.to_html()`. Not ideal, but at least one potential workaround for you.

```
from IPython.display import display_html
display_html(pd.DataFrame([cube]).to_html().replace("\\n", "\n<br>").replace("CUBE", '<b style="color: red">CUBE</b>'), raw=True)
```

[image]

Comment: that's a viable solution.  I can probably manipulate further as well.  Thanks.